# Windows Mobile 6 - Handheld terminal How do I check the clock every time I turn it on

Tags: api, time, windows-mobile

in some cases when I turn on the device it shows the time as a different time and I need to fix it. How can I handle this automatically with an api or similar application? Can someone help?

Comment: What manufacturer do you have?

Comment: I already fix this problem.  if u need something u can look > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652907/c-sharp-windows-mobile-app-kernel32-dll-error