# C# - Windows Mobile App - Kernel32.dll Error

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

This is my code:

```
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError =true)]
        private static extern bool GetSystemTime(out SYSTEMTIME systemTime);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError =
        true)]
        private static extern bool SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME systemTime);
        public struct SYSTEMTIME
        {
            public short Year;
            public short Month;
            public short DayOfWeek;
            public short Day;
            public short Hour;
            public short Minute;
            public short Second;
            public short Milliseconds;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now;



            SYSTEMTIME zaman = new SYSTEMTIME();
            zaman.Day = 25;
            zaman.Month = 9;
            zaman.Year = 2010;
            zaman.Hour = 14;
            zaman.Minute = 45;
            SetSystemTime(ref zaman);

            label1.Text = zaman.Day.ToString();
            label2.Text = zaman.Month.ToString();
            label3.Text = zaman.Year.ToString();
        }
```

The situation I want to do is to set the data I entered as time in windows.

The error I got:  Can't find PInvoke DLL 'kernel32'.

How can fix this? Any ideas will be good for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we write ' coredll ' instead of kernel32, the error is fixed